# How to Configure a user/password in OpenVPN Server

Tags: server, openvpn

I've installed OpenVPN server. Everything works except I now want to require a user/password to connect. I can find all kinds of info on user/password for clients but nothing that explains how to set/require a user/password on the server. Can someone point me in the right direction? TIA.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you want to make the *client* enter a user id and password to connect to the *server*? Because that's normally not done. It uses keys and certificates instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a word of warning, certificate authentication is the prefered method for a reason and using alternative authentication mechanisms such as username and password will reduce security.

That said username and password is available as an alternate authentication scheme in OpenVPN. The documentation on the OpenVPN website explains how to configure this should you still wish to do so.

The documentation you need can be found at the following URL:
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#auth

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using certificates but not sure how secure that is. Perhaps I am a belt and suspenders kind of person but if someone gets a copy of the opvn file would not a user/password add a second level of security?

Comment: My apologies I did not realize you wanted to use both certificate and credentials together. This can be done via the same auth-user-pass and auth-user-pass-verify options simply omit to add the client-cert-not-required. If you are aiming for the additional security I recommend using username and password alongside individual client certificates too. This effectively functions as full Multi-Factor Authentication as it requires both possession of a device containing the client certificate and knowledge of the matching credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the help.